# How to find aspect ratio of all the characters in a binary word using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

suppose this is the word "S I D" in an image. I have to find out the aspect ratio of all the connected components(in this example it will be 3 components)

Answer (score 0):

Use `bwlabel` and `regionprops` to get the `'BoundingBox'` property for each connected component.
Then you can get the aspect ratio by dividing the width and the height of the bounding-box (last 2 entries of the 4-vector describing each bounding box).

Best of luck...

Comment: I would be really grateful if you can provide a short code. I am new to this

Comment: @user2193718 this website is NOT for writing code for you. It is for **helping** you do it yourself. You must show some effort on your part: some code/algorithm. Go to matlab help center, google for `bwlabel` and `regionprops`. Try working it out yourself. If you have further problems down the line - post them as new questions showing us what you have done and what you have learned.

Comment: I tried this  L = bwlabel(BW);
s = regionprops( L, 'BoundingBox' );
AR = s.BoundingBox(4) / s.BoundingBox(3);  But I am getting error in last line

Comment: @user2193718 run in debugger and see what is the size of `s` you got. it is NOT a scalar, but a struct array.